# Extract certain tuples from a list

Tags: python, loops, url, tuples

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about this, but I have created a list of Tuples which consist of a form type and a corresponding URL. I would like to isolate those Tuples which have a form type of 10-K and have tried using a code which I found on Stack Overflow. However I have ended up with a new list with no contents, despite the fact I know that there are several 10-K form types. 
I am a beginner so please be kind.

```
file = '10-K'
req_urls = []

for tuple in typeandurls:
     if file in tuple:
           req_urls.append
     else:
           pass
```

Comment: `req_urls.append` Note how you aren't giving anything to `append`. Do you mean `req_urls.append(tuple)`?

Comment: Also, note that you don't need `else: pass`. That's doing the same thing as if there were no `else` at all.

Comment: Thank you, those comments all make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively a good way could be to use a list comprehension, like so:

```
file = '10-K'
req_urls = [tup for tup in typeandurls if file in tup]
```

Here I assume that
`file in tuple` is how you want to test if an element should belong to the output collection.

Upside of doing that is that your code would be more readable at first sight